# Why does my code not add the lists it is given even though it is told to do so?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision

I have been trying to add the RGB values of each pixel in an image but for some reason the code gives me an warning and refuses to add the values or to store them in the a list.

error:

```
RuntimeWarning: Main.py:46: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in ubyte_scalars
  rgb2 = red2[counter]+green2[counter]+blue2[counter]
```

code:

```
import cv2

lib = ['Map1.png']

Read = list(cv2.imread(lib[0]))

while True:

    for i in range(len(Read)):  # y coords
        for j in range(len(Read[i])):  # x coords
            blue = list(Read[i][j])[0]
            green = list(Read[i][j])[0]
            red = list(Read[i][j])[0]
            rgb = blue + green + red
            lib3 = []
            lib3.append(rgb)
            print(lib3)
```

Map1:

[image]

Comment: How is that "error" (it clearly says it's a warning) relevant to the example code? There aren't 46 lines there to begin with, and no sight of any of the 5 variables involved in the statement that causes the warning...

Comment: I dont really care if the error is a warning the problem is that it is not appending anything to my list even though my image has colour

Comment: It does append, a single value in every iteration. But also on every iteration you create a new empty list and throw the old one away... so all you ever end up is a list with a single value in it.

Comment: You are repeatedly creating a *new* list to store the value of `rgb`. Put `lib3` outside the loop. (Outside *which* loop isn't clear; maybe in the `while` loop but before the `for i in ..` loop?

Comment: But if I put it outside will it append all the values or just the last one because it it not adding the rgb for every iteration

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Why all those list constructors, why the loops? Say `img` is the output of `imread`, if I wanted a Python list where each value is a sum of red, green and blue intensities of a pixel, then I'd do something like `img.sum(axis=2).tolist()`... which would likely run several orders of magnitude faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cv2.imread()` method by default returns an array of type `uint8`, which stands for Unsigned integer *(**0 to 255**)*.

The warning

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in ubyte_scalars
```

is caused by this line of your code:

```
rgb = blue + green + red
```

You see, if the variables `blue`, `green` and `red` all contain an integer ranging from `0` to `255`, then adding them together will likely **result in a number that is greater than `255`** from time to time.

Keeping in mind that the data type of the variables `blue`, `green` and `red` are `uint8`, and not `int`, we can see why the warning occurred:

```
>>> type(red)
<class 'numpy.uint8'>
```

The way you can get rid of the warning is to convert the image type from `uint8` to a type that will support numbers greater than `255`, for example, `uint16` *(0 to 65535)*:

```
cv2.imread(lib[0]).astype("uint16")
```

---

Do note that there is a slight flaw in these lines of your code:

```
blue = list(Read[i][j])[0]
green = list(Read[i][j])[0]
red = list(Read[i][j])[0]
```

It should be

```
blue = list(Read[i][j])[0]
green = list(Read[i][j])[1]
red = list(Read[i][j])[2]
```

Or better:

```
blue, green, red = Read[i][j]
```

Comment: It gives me the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'astype'`

Comment: When `cv2.imread(lib[0])` returns `None` *(which is what caused the error)*, it means that the path `lib[0]` is not a valid file path. You can try adding the line `import os; print(os.path.exists(lib[0]))` before the line that caused the error, and see if the file exists.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this piece of code do what you want ?

```py
img_with_rgb_sum = list(map(lambda row : list(map(lambda color : sum(color), row)), Read))
```

### Input

```py
Read = [[[171, 127, 30], [19, 213, 66], [19, 187, 2], [2, 104, 247]], 
       [[217, 120, 234], [47, 114, 57], [68, 59, 152], [104, 204, 205]], 
       [[162, 156, 74], [209, 242, 95], [184, 169, 169], [73, 245, 206]], 
       [[86, 233, 254], [137, 122, 221], [215, 221, 101], [195, 171, 52]]]
```

### Output

```py
img_with_rgb_sum = [[328, 298, 208, 353], 
                   [571, 218, 279, 513], 
                   [392, 546, 522, 524], 
                   [573, 480, 537, 418]]
```

Answer (score 0):

seems you only take the blue value. try:

```
blue = list(Read[i][j])[0]
green = list(Read[i][j])[1]
red = list(Read[i][j])[2]
```

also move `lib3 = []` to before your loops otherwise you are overriding your list for each pixel